# How to host an adaptive website in NodeJS and Express?

Tags: node.js, express

I am planning to make an ecommerce application however I do not wish to have a responsive site. The desktop site will support tablet and will be some what responsive.

The mobile site will be a dedicated mobile site with a seperate view. I normally use Laravel or a PHP approach to detect the mobile and do server-side rendering based on the device (some people call these adaptive sites or `m dot com` sites)

My question is. Using Express, Node and a JavaScript approach can I achieve this?

All users who visit site.com will either site a mobile code or a desktop code depending on device. We currently do this at namshi.com (See Chrome and change device and the code base changes)

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mobile-detect  (express middleware) -

Comment: Of course it is possible. You can use the same logic in node than you would in PHP.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, of course you can do it. As you do it in PHP or any other language you need to find device type using user agent from the request. Below code uses [express-device](https://github.com/rguerreiro/express-device) to render different `ejs` files.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// set the view engine to ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

var device = require('express-device');
app.use(device.capture());

app.get('/hello',function(req,res) {
   if(req.device.type === 'phone'){
       res.render('phoneEjs');
   } else {
       res.render('desktopEjs');
   }
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log("Listening to Port 3000");
```